# How to merge MySQL columns into one column if there are empty values in the table?

Tags: mysql, sql, select, insert

I thought it would be better if I ask you by showing images.

[image]

Here is my `people` table. As you can see, it was a bad design idea. Some people have more than one occupation (writer/actress), so I will use a junction table to make it work, and get rid of `people` table. My question is, how can I move all of these values from `people` to my `person` table, without copying the empty values? (For instance, people_id = 1 contains only a director name and other ones are empty.

The following query adds empty values, too. And I also can't select all all the columns with it.

```
INSERT INTO person (person_name)
          SELECT director_name
          FROM people
          WHERE people_id < 150000;
```

My person table. I want to copy all names from people to person table, in person_name column.
[image]

Comment: What is the problem with this query? Your query will work as you want

Comment: What do you mean by "copy empty values"? If the empty values you're referring to are the ones in the other columns ("musician_name", "translator_name", etc.), they don't get copied by your query, simply because you don't select them.

Comment: Guys, thanks for your comments. Gordon's answer solved my problem. I might have asked my question a little vague. When I used the query below, some NULL values were being added to person_name column.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Presumably, you want to compare for `NULL`/blank/whatever:

```
INSERT INTO person (person_name)
      SELECT director_name
      FROM people
      WHERE people_id < 150000 AND
            director_name IS NOT NULL AND
            director_name <> '';
```